# Microsoft Azure Can not assign virtual network to virtual machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

In the azure managment portal,  I created a Virtual Network, but when i go to create the virtual machines,  It didn't give me the screen that let me assign that vm to the virtual network. Why?

Answer (score 2):

How long did you wait between the time the Virtual Network was created and the time when trying to create the VM?  I've seen sometimes where it takes a little bit (less than 30 sec.), or refresh the management portal.  Also, the VM must be provisioned into a VNET. You can't currently assign an existing VM to a VNET.

Comment: More than 30 seconds for sure, i wa playing around for quite a while back and forth. Actual one screen showing those options for 1 second then hided , that screen is for setup the endpoints . One thing i need to mention is i am on trial plan.